# Checked baggage for domestic connecting-flight in China from international flight

Tags: transit, luggage, china, connecting-flights

I am planning to travel to Xiamen, China from Berlin, Germany and some of the flights have a stopover in a Chinese city like Guangzhou or Beijing. In this case, do I need to take my luggage first from arrival and checking in again my baggage for the domestic flight to Xiamen?